# Laravel File Upload to Amazon S3 throws error 'Unable to write file at location: filename.jpg'

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I am building an application that will upload files to `Amazon S3` and able to retrieve it. I created `AWS` Account and `S3` `Bucket mybucket-ph-filess`. I also create `IAM` user with inline policy access:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-ph-filess",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-ph-filess/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It also has AmazonS3FullAccess policy.

The Access Key `ID` and secret access key were also generated and properly configured the `Laravel` `config/filesystem.php` which looks like this:

```
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'region' => 'ap-southeast-1',
            'bucket' => 'mybucket-ph-filess',
            'url' => 'https://mybucket-ph-filess.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/',
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw' => true,
        ],
```

My route looks like this:

```
Route::get('/', [ImageController::class,'create']);
Route::post('/', [ImageController::class,'store']);
```

The image Controller's `create()` and `store()` function is like this:

```
public function create(){
        return view('create'); // simple form with file attachment id/named 'image'
    }

public function store(Request $request){

        $path = $request->file('image')->store('','s3');
        return  $path;
    }
```

I am expecting that when the store command is fired, the image file will be stored to the bucket and it will return the `url` of the file. but it is throwing error like this:

League\Flysystem\UnableToWriteFile `(PHP 8.1.8, laravel 10.8.0)`
Unable to write file at location: `y7oLZxBw4HMxhuPe6uqRxpzse5HP8kQzFZcO1NCj.jpg.`

I already run the following commands:

```
composer require `league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3:^3.0`

php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear
```

If anyone would enlighten me on what I am missing here, It will be so much appreciated. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I think you need to set permission for the folder(chmod) where this library trying to upload the files at.

Answer (score 3):

```
/*store video on amazon*/
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $filename = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $amaozn_url = url('https://lmszoom.s3--------------/image/'.$filename); //to access file
        $file->storeAs('image',$filename, 's3');
```

Comment: Don't just dump code as answer. Please add some clarification on what you changed, why OP's code doesn't work etc.

Comment: @brombeer here he did mistake $request->file('image')->store('','s3');  miss storeAs and bucket folder name not given also.. i think OP's understand his mistake after see my answer

Comment: Thanks. OP might understand his mistake, he might not. Other users might understand the mistake - or not. Better safe than sorry